# JavaScript: Least repetitive way to access sub-property of a property that may not exist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, properties

In the code below, I can't just do `o.property.startsWith` because there's a chance that `o` doesn't have a property called `property` on it. So I have to do this check everytime.

```
  if (o.hasOwnProperty('property')) {
    console.log(o.property.startsWith('hello'));
  }
```

Is there a simpler or less repetitive way of accessing a sub-property of a property that may not exist?

Comment: Why not just `if (o.property)`? Or `if (o.property && o.property.startsWith)`?

Answer (score 0):

How about just:

```
console.log((o.property || "").startsWith('hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on using this validation many times, you could add it to a function to prevent code duplicates:

```
function validateProperty(property, startsWith) {
    return property && property.startWith(startsWith);
}
console.log(validateProperty(o.property, 'hello'));
console.log(validateProperty(o.property2, 'bye'));
```

Plus, it might interest you to know that the sub-properties can be accessed via brackets:

```
o.property === o['property']
```